# The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database for some reports

Tags: sql-server, encryption, reporting-services

I am using some SSRS reports in some applications that I developed using Visual Studio.

Recently I noticed that my report server url is giving me the following error message.

"*The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database. You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content. (rsReportServerDisabled) Get Online Help
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors*"

[image]

I can't go delete the encryption details and try to set the data connections again as many posts suggest because there are a lot of SSRS reports in this server and I don't know the username and passwords to connect to all databases.

Further, I noticed the following.

1. My SSRS home page displays this error message
2. Some applications using reports hosted in this report server displays the same message
3. Other few applications using reports hosted in this report server works as expected without any error messages

Where should I look and what should I do about this? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For others seeing this error due to changing the account under which SSRS runs, the key is to migrate via the SQL console, not services.msc, and backup the encryption keys.  If you have the original credentials still available, migrate back to the original account via services.msc, then use the console to migrate to the new account correctly.  Details: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5787/change-the-sql-server-reporting-services-service-account/